# Android store last 10 search values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an app that searches in a database. I want to store last 10 search values (and I want them to remain even if the user closes the app) to use them as an adapter in AutoCompleteTextView.

SharedPreferences doesn't seem to support arrays or arraylists. What's the best approach here?

Comment: You could easily encode them with JSON and save them in one SharedPreference

Comment: Since API 11 there is a method called putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)

Comment: Yup, but my app supports API 7.

Comment: Then I would use a JSON formatted string with all 10 values or create 10 items in the SharedPreferences. SharedPreferences are saved as XML and 10 XML-Tags is not that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table in a `SQLiteDatabase` to store the search history, and use the standard SQL API to access it.

Or you can use a [file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) in XML, JSON, YAML, CSV, plain text, or whatever you like to persist the history. The advantage is simplicity and (maybe) performance. The disadvantage is that you'll have to serialize and deserialize yourself (a possible variation is to serialized a Java object directly)

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences support boolean int, float, long and String.

BUT ArrayList are Serializable, so if you also declare you object Serializable, you can encode them into a ByteBuffer with an ObjectOutputStream, then convert this byteBuffer into a String, and finally store it into a SharedPreferences, or better to a binary file (as bytebuffer).

In your case, where you just have to save String, it is easer run through every element of the array and save them as "arrayName"+index, and finally save the size of the array.